# Using php How to change password containing three fields old pwd, current pwd, confirm pwd?

Tags: php

Using three fields **old password , current password , confirm password**.

1st condition:In this if old password is not matched With DB then message should display password is not matched.

2nd condition:  Current and Confirm password should match then password will be changed.

//Here is my php code:
     **I am not able to fetch the old password from database**

```
<?php



$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "user_db";

// Create connection
//var_name = new mysqli(host, useername, password, database); 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else{


}

?>
         <?php  require_once('session.php');
             if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                                    {
        //These three fields I am using:

                             $old_password=$_POST['old_password'];
                             $user_password = $_POST['user_password'];
                             $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];
                        $query = "Select * from user_tbl where user_id = '3'";
                   $q=$conn->query($query);
                    // I am not able to fetch and check old password with db

                    if($q->num_rows>0)
                        { $r1=$q->fetch_assoc();{

                        }


                    //$chg_pwd1= mysql_fetch_array($query);

                    $data_pwd=$chg_pwd1['password'];
            }
                                        if($data_pwd==$old_password)
            {
                                            if($user_password==$confirm_password)
            {
            $update="update user_tbl set password ='$user_password' where user_id ='3'";
    echo "<script>alert('Update Sucessfully'); window.location=''change_password.php'</script>";}
       else{
    echo "<script>alert('Your new and Retype Password is not match'); window.location=''change_password.php'</script>";}}
     else{
         echo "<script>alert('Your old password is wrong'); window.location='change_password.php'</script>";}}

                    ?> 

    //Html code
        <form method="post" >

                <label>Enter Old Password</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="old_password">
                <label>Enter Password</label>
                    <input type="password"  id="user_password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="user_password" >
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="Confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirm_password"  >


                    <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Update">
                </form>
```

I am new in php please help !
        Thanks in advance

Comment: Your Code can't understand what is this ` if($q->num_rows>0)
                    { $r1=$q->fetch_assoc();{`

Comment: @ Nawin I am trying to fetch the old password from db thats what i am unable to fetch. In place of these what should to write to fetch the password

Comment: Your query is ` $query` and what is `$q` in the `if` condition?

Comment: @Nawin $q for conn:  $q=$conn->query($query);

Comment: Did you get the data from your query?

Comment: What are you using to connect to the database? PDO?

Comment: Sidenote: You have a lot of different issues as you store your passwords in plain text. Look up hashing and salting please.

Comment: Sidenote 2: SQL injections would be possible in the `$update` query.

Comment: @nawin no i am not able to get data.

Comment: Then your query is mistage check your query first

Comment: @nawin normally i was run the query in DB that time its fetching the correct  data.but in page its not fetching. password is in the encoded format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected the database? And if yes, please check if you are getting the typed value of $oldpassword. To check this underneath $oldpassword = $_POST['old_password'];

Write print_r($oldpassword);die; and check if you are getting the typed old password or not.

Comment: So, that is the issue. Your form is not submitting. What have you done in the input name? Can you share the form part? So, I can look at it.

Comment: already in question i had mention about form tag. please check it once

Comment: You haven't added action that is why it is not doing anything. Write this <form method="post" action="">